# SASS работа со строками

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

День добрый.
Пишу миксины для работы GRID в IE11

```
@mixin grid-template-columns($args, $gap) {
  -ms-grid-columns: $args;
  grid-template-columns: $args;
  grid-gap: $gap;
}
```

В -ms-grid-columns, если в $args больше одного параметра нужно после каждого, кроме последнего подставить $gap. Самому ума не хватает.

Пример использования:

```
#content_grid {
  @include grid-template-columns(1fr 25% 25%, 10px);
}
```

Должно получиться так:

```
#content_grid {
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 10px 25% 10px 25%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 25% 25%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

Пример без поддержки IE

https://codepen.io/mourat-boutry/pen/wxmpOx

Comment: для начала, `args` надо массивом сделать, потом уже `join()`, не уверен будет ли в миксине работать, можно и циклом подставить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как Sass предоставляет не много методов для работы со списками значений, можно создать новый список и заполнить его на основе $args, вставляя после каждого элемента $gap.

Создать новый список можно объявив переменную, например:

```
$list: ();
```

Для прохода по списку `$args` можно воспользоваться циклом `@for`.

```
@for $i from 1 through length($args) {
```

Внутри цикла получаем значение текущего элемента с помощью функции `nth`

```
$arg: nth($args, $i);
```

Добавляем это значение с помощью функции `append`

```
$list: append($list, $arg);
```

Чтобы не добавлять `$gap` после последнего элемента нужно проверить условие, что текущий индекс меньше длины списка

```
@if $i < length($args){
```

И если это так, добавить `$gap` с помощью функции `append`

Далее для свойства просто использовать значение `$list`

```
-ms-grid-columns: $list;
```

Пример в сборе:

```
@mixin grid-template-columns($args, $gap) {
  $list: ();
  @for $i from 1 through length($args) {
    $arg: nth($args, $i);
    $list: append($list, $arg);
    @if $i < length($args){
      $list: append($list, $gap);
    }
  }
  -ms-grid-columns: $list;
  grid-template-columns: $args;
  grid-gap: $gap;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это хорошо работает

Comment: Доделал миксины.
Работает в IE 10/11
https://codepen.io/mourat-boutry/pen/vaRjLG

Comment: @Mourat, если ответ помог можешь отметить его галочкой